# Issue population value on input with php due to "

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate a html field using php but if there is a " on the variable it just closes the value paramenter. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<input type="text" name="txtnome" class="form-control" value="<?php echo "$nome" ?>" required>
```

Comment: do this "<?php echo '$nome' ?>"

Comment: @NitinDhomse that will just print $nome on the field.

Comment: why the heck you cannot all finally learn the difference between variable **name** and variable **value**

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that has nothing to do with what I asked

Comment: it does. neither of you see the difference.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski can you show me where? because as far as I can see I'm just pre-populating a form with a variable called $nome.

Comment: in the code where you put `echo "$nome"` and `$nome` is quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtnome" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($nome) ?>" required>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Since

```
echo "$nome";
echo '$nome';
echo $nome;
```

are identical to each other, it'll only work with `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Instead of populating with Tes"te' it populated with Tes\

Comment: it should populate with `Tes\"te\'`. Take another look. This way is the correct way to escape quoted strings in attributes.

Comment: @TahaPaksu HTML doesn't identify escape characters I think... like \" or \'

Comment: I want the input content to be like the one on the top https://image.prntscr.com/image/cFItIieYR7KzRzjU1f1ttw.png

Comment: can you try htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Just waiting the minimum time to accept it